# how to call node from overlay package from a package in hydro default installation

Tags: slam, navigation, clearpath, husky, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed husky_navigation which is the standard navigation package for the Clearpath Husky robot directly from the hydro installation ros-hydro-husky-navigation. I'm running a launchfile within that package that calls the slam_gmapping node of the gmapping package.

However, I wanted to modify the behavior of slam_gmapping a bit and therefore created an overlay of the gmapping package and made the required changes. This node now functions as required. But when I launch the husky_navigation launchfile, it still launches the hydro default installation of slam_gmapping and NOT my overlay.

How do I specify this in the launchfile so that it calls my overlayed package?

Thank you.

PS - Let me know if I wasn't clear with some of the terminology here. I don't know what a default debian package installation of a hydro package is called.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188310/how-to-call-node-from-overlay-package-from-a-package-in-hydro-default-installation/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-30**:
Where does roscd slam_gmapping lead you to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should happen automatically if you've sourced the overlay with your modified packages in it before you run roslaunch.

Perhaps there's something unusual about the way you run the husky navigation launch file that is resetting the environment?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-31**:
I haven't changed anything in the default launch file. I sourced the overlay again and it worked but I know that I had sourced it earlier too. So there's got to be something I'm running that's resetting the environment. How would I find something that resets the environment? Thank you.